# Assign some data fields to DropDownList item

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to **assign 2 data fields to a DropDownList item** because I want to **display 2 values** at click at an item in different elements (for example, 2 textboxes).

For example: *at click on a DDL item, that a value of data field named "example" displayed in one TXTBOX and other of a data field named "definition" displayed in other TXTBOX*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have do something like this, you can just separate the two values with some sort of delimiter (, or | or whatever), and then parse them out when it's selected and you have to display them.

```
Item.Value = "VALUE1,VALUE2";

string[] Values = Item.Value.Split(',');

txt1.Text = Values[0];
txt2.Text = Values[1];
```

Comment: I've assigned to DropDownList.DataValueField only 1 data field.

Comment: And that code doesn't work because only are displayed the datavalefield names (example and definition; one per textbox). How can I fix tnat?

Comment: You will have to manually assign values to the DropDownList. You can't assign multiple values by assigning the DataValueField unless your have a combined column in your datasource. Loop through your DataSource rows and add ListItems to the DropDownList. Assign whatever you want, their value, the text, etc.

Comment: Hello, I' tried to follow your steps without the"DATAVALUEFIELD" property and I get an error message as the following when I select some items of the DDL: "index were the size of the array".

Comment: Throw your code up on http://pastebin.com/ or something similar and I can look at it.

Comment: Given that, and the error you mentioned, the array doesn't have 2 items in it. Meaning the value in the selected item didn't have a , in it when you did Split on it. What is the SelectedItem.Value when you debug.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3966/discussion-between-blake-and-amgarciac)